# Google Sheets issue comparing dates

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having issues with a date comparison producing an incorrect result and cannot identify why.

I'm using this for a more complex formula but identified this logic as being the reason the other formula is not working correctly. In this very simple formula: IF(start date < new date,"T","F"), all of the results should be "T" but are showing up as "F". I verified all date values are dates with ISDATE() and the strange thing is using DATEDIF correctly calculates the date difference, so I'm having trouble figuring out why the IF comparison isn't working.

Please see screenshots below. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tested it here and it worked as expected. Wouldn't it be the case to split a chunck of data and make it available so folks can pular dentro and help?

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to - it has too many formulas linked to sensitive information and when I copy the relevant information onto a new sheet the formula works as expected. It looks like the issue is with the Start Date being pulled from other tabs in the spreadsheet using a VLOOKUP, but I added TEXT() around the VLOOKUP to make sure the output is in a date format...when I copy/paste the Start Date, the formula works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like adding `DATEVALUE()` around the `TEXT(VLOOKUP(),"M/D/YYYY")` formula seemed to do the trick. There was an issue with the formatting of the date value being pulled through the `vlookup` despite it registering as a date value, and adding `DATEVALUE` around that formula solved it.